# VM in virtual network - cannot RDP via public DNS

Tags: azure

I need to create a new VM which is connected to virtual network so that I can promote VM to domain controller. I had followed all steps, created new affinity group, storage, network, dns

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/17/step-by-step-building-a-windows-server-2012-active-directory-forest-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure.aspx#.Ub9O6PnbNPQ

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/

After VM is provisioned, I changed the public RDP port back to 3389 which is opened in my environment.

After all this setup I cannot RDP into the new VM from my environment.

I have an old VM which is not part of the virtual network and I can RDP into from my environment, so this confirms that port 3389 is not blocked.

I then RDP into the old VM and then RDP into the new VM, and it works!

I don't want to make any conclusions but it seems to me that once in virtual network it is not possible to connect to VM via public DNS. This contradicts with statement

> **Connectivity to the internet:** You will still enjoy the ability to
>   connect services hosted in virtual networks to the internet through
>   the public IP address that has been assigned for your service.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx

Can anyone confirm or reject my assumption?

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm the symptoms. Did you find the solution?

Comment: I can RDP using internal IP and default port once connected to virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that your new VM's endpoint for RDP is set correctly?  Microsoft has recently changed the default settings to randomize the public endpoint port for additional security as specified here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/

Comment: Yes, I changed randomly generated port back to 3389, as stated in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to figure this out, but I followed the guide below and couldn't RDP into any of the VMs I created in the virtual network.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/create-virtual-network/

Things I tried:

- Recreate virtual network
- Recreate cloud service
- Resize VM - this causes the VM to be moved to a different hosting server, triggering new IPs

In the end, what fixed it for me was creating the virtual network with a 192.168.0.0/16 address space. I also created just one subnet (192.168.4.0/24) and adding the new VMs into that subnet.

Hope this helps others.